# Which formal power series can be expressed as a rational fraction?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, power-series, formal-power-series

Which formal power series $$A(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n=a_0+a_1 x+ a_2x^2+\dots$$ around the center $c=0$ can be expressed as a rational fraction, i.e. $$A(x)=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)},$$
where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are polynomials?

Note that I am talking about *formal* power series and *formal* polynomials, that is, we consider them to be syntactic objects rather than discussing function-theoretic/analytic properties (in particular, it does not matter whether our formal power series $A(x)$ converges).

Comment: I wonder: You can't about growth of syntactical objects. Could you add some explanation?

Comment: Is this where you should look? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14842/when-a-formal-power-series-is-a-rational-function-in-disguise

Comment: I think at least one dissertation that covers this: [Avila, Benigno Rafael Parra. On rational and periodic power series and on sequential and polycyclic error-correcting codes. Ohio University, 2009.](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/!etd.send_file?accession=ohiou1257886601&disposition=inline)

Comment: Could you please give page and result?